# What is the most effective way to copy time (hh, mm) from one datetime to another?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, momentjs

I'm trying to write a calendar with timepicker, so that when you change the date, the time stays the same. Both fields (calendar and time) in html use the same variable (`vm.inputDate`) and I don't want to change that.
Right now I have this function, that triggers on date change:

```
vm.keepTimeUnchanged = function(changedDateTime, oldDateTime) {
            var hours = oldDateTime.getHours();
            var minutes = oldDateTime.getMinutes();

            if (!moment(vm.inputDate).isSame((changedDateTime), 'day')) {
                vm.inputDate = changedDateTime;
                vm.inputDate.setHours(hours, minutes);
            }
            return vm.inputDate;        
        }
```

This works, but I would like to keep the time in exact same format, as in the original value, without getting separately seconds and milliseconds. Is there any way to do that? And is there any better way to perform the whole operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's either setting date in one moment or setting time in another, cannot be much better than that. Notice that when time is set, it may be desirable to set seconds and milliseconds as well.

Moment API allows to do that in different flavours, like:

```
date1 = moment(date1.toArray().slice(0, 4).concat(
  date2.toArray().slice(4)
);
```

Or:

```
let { years, months, date } = date1.toObject();
date1 = date2.clone().set({ years, months, date });
```

The same thing is less attractive in ES5, yet it's possible to make it look better with Lodash `pick`:

```
date1 = date2.clone().set(_.pick(date1.toObject(), 'years', 'months', 'date'));
```

Comment: Thanks! At least with this solution I could set the date in one line. I'll settle for that!